# .PO to .MO - Programmatic Conversion (PHP)

Tags: php, windows, linux, translation, gettext

I am planning to allow users to generate .POT files/.PO files through a PHP user interface as part of  CMS solution.  Once these files have been generated (the easy bit) I would like to allow my system to automatically convert these files into .MO files in response to a user (POST) request.

I have seen the following question on SO:

[.po to .mo convertor in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181681/po-to-mo-convertor-in-php)

**I understand that I could run `msgfmt` by using PHP's `exec()` function, but that seems to be a Linux only solution, if I am correct?  How would I do this on other operating systems?**  Some example code of how this may be done in practice would also be really useful, if anybody would be kind enough to demonstrate.  This is quite different from the work I usually do!

This is only a concept at the moment but I hope I'm going along the right lines.  If there are any additional thoughts/suggestions you have regarding this method, I'd be glad to hear them.  Background information follows.

**Additional Background Information - Not required:**

I am retrieving the original English text by parsing simple template files that consist of nothing more than basic HTML and calls to `<?php _('the gettext method'); ?>`.  These templates are parsed when edited/saved and the language entries are retrieved.  The .POT file will then be generated.  The user would now have to edit translations manually (through a simple interface, not directly) to update/prepare all the .PO files.  Once this is done, I would need to be able to convert them to .MO files, as is the title of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are also PHP-only reimplementations of `msgfmt` if that is what you are looking for:

- [php-msgfmt](http://wordpress-soc-2007.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/moeffju/php-msgfmt/)
- [php.mo](http://web.archive.org/web/20111226233411/https://github.com/josscrowcroft/php.mo)/[gh](https://github.com/phpmo/php.mo)

As alternative there would also be the [Translate/Pootle](http://pootle.translatehouse.org/) webapp, with its [php2po](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/php2po.html) script, but there must also be some .mo conversion functions in it... (Ooops no, it's in Python.)

Comment: @marioThat php.mo class looks excellent.  Thank you for bringing it to my attention - I will mark as the answer shortly!

Do you happen to know if there are any PHP implementations that scan a given directory to create a POT file, too?  I've googled around but can't find anything so far.

Comment: That would just require a simple regex and reading through the files. I've certainly seen something like this. Most PHP apps that use a double underscore `__()` gettext wrapper function have one. IIRC you might find one in e.g. PhpWiki. (it's surprisingly difficult to google another..)

Comment: Coming to think of it, I've seen Magento use the double underscore too.  I might look and see what they've done.  All I have been able to think of is a `glob()` and `preg_match_all()` (as you suggest), although I can imagine the execution time will be quite nasty if the application is sufficiently large... Anyway, thanks once again.

Comment: The link for php.mo is dead, could you fix it?

Comment: tried both, both fail to create valid .mo, only last .po key is imported from the .mo

Answer (score 2):

Both PHP's `exec` and the `msgfmt` GNU gettext utility are not a linux only solution. They work on multiple computer systems. As with PHP you can compile for multiple platforms (as it's done naturally), so the `exec` command is available on mutliple systems, the same applies to `msgfmt`. Start on the [GNU gettext homepage](http://www.gnu.org/s/gettext/) to obtain a version for your system.

Answer (score 1):

try https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext.git

```
use Gettext\Translations;
chdir('....');
        $translations = Translations::fromPoFile('messages.po');
        $translations->toMoFile('messages.mo');
```