# Is there a PHP library for parsing gettext PO POT files?

Tags: php, parsing, gettext, po

if is not in PHP, is possible use some command line tools which convert PO file into some structured format e.g. XML or some other which I can simple process in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.PO to .MO - Programmatic Conversion (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167924/po-to-mo-programmatic-conversion-php)

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: As of 2018/05, the best options are:

- https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html
- https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-i18n/translation/

See http://www.phptherightway.com#i18n_l10n_title

There are some:

- https://github.com/jyxo/php/tree/master/Jyxo/Gettext
- https://github.com/clinisbut/PHP-po-parser
- http://code.google.com/p/php-po-parser/
- http://pear.php.net/package/File_Gettext/redirected
- http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/tree/HEAD:/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Gettext

The last one is part of Drupal, and it's probably the most maintained.

Comment: +1 for https://github.com/clinisbut/PHP-po-parser

Answer (score 2):

Some simple regular expressions will allow you to parse .PO/.POT files.  I did a similar thing recently.  Take the following regex from a script I have recently written:

```
$poMsgIdAndMsgStrRegex = '/^#\s*(.+?)\nmsgid "(.+?)"\nmsgstr "(.+?)"/m';
```

This does only capture the final comment line but it has so far been suitable for my purposes.  You may need to adapt it.

Anyway, you can use the above regex with `preg_match_all()` to capture all `MsgId` and `MsgStr` strings into an array of matches.  Once you have the array then you can put it into any format you wish.

There may be libraries for doing this but I have not seen any.

**Edit:** You may also want to check out the PHP class for converting.po files .mo format that is referred to in the 'possible duplicate' comment.  It doesn't sound like it will solve your problem (since you want to convert .po files to XML), but it is worth examining anyway.  It helped me a lot.

Comment: This will work for simplistic POs, but not ones with any plural forms, or multi-line entries.  Just a heads-up.  We're working on a library, and I will post a link here when it becomes available.

Comment: @DougW - Did you ever finish your library?

Comment: @rcourtna - We've written one, but haven't had a chance to convert it over to a form that we could open source.  I'd love to do it, but unfortunately it'll have to happen as we've got the time to spare.  In the meantime, I can point you to a library called Babel that does a decent job of parsing POs.  We've run into a few issues with UTF-8 encodings, etc, but it should work for most needs.  http://babel.edgewall.org/